# How do I grab total number of days selected between two dates?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have this jquery script that allows a user to choose a start date and end date:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#txtToDate').datepicker({ showOn: 'button',
            buttonImage: 'images/20/calendar200.gif',
            buttonImageOnly: true, onSelect: function () { },
            onClose: function () { $(this).focus(); }
        });


        $('#txtFromDate').datepicker({ showOn: 'button',
            buttonImage: 'images/20/calendar200.gif',
            buttonImageOnly: true, onSelect:
        function (dateText, inst) {
            $('#txtToDate').datepicker("option", 'minDate', new Date(dateText));
        }
      ,
            onClose: function () { $(this).focus(); }
        });
        $('#txtToDate').datepicker({
       // Your other options here
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var days = ($("#txtToDate").datepicker('getDate') - 
            $("#txtFromDate").datepicker('getDate'))/(24*60*60*1000);
        $('#numOfDays').val(days);
       console.log(days);
    }
  }
  );  

    });  
</script>
```

Then I have a textbox control:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="numOfDays" class="fptextbox12" runat="server" style="width:60px;"></asp:TextBox>
```

Once a user chooses a start date and an end date, we would like the total number of days in that box.

Any ideas how to calculate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `onSelect` option to the datepicker and calculate the number of days.

```
$('#txtToDate').datepicker({
        // Your other options here
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            var days = ($("#txtToDate").datepicker('getDate') - 
                $("#txtFromDate").datepicker('getDate'))/(24*60*60*1000);
            $('#numOfDays').val(days);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: thank you for the prompt response.

I am new to jquery. Where in the current script do I put your code?

I tried running and I am getting the following error:

` Unable to get value of the property 'getTime': object is null or undefined`

Comment: no more errors but the value of date1 - date2 is not showing up on numOfDays box.

Any ideas?

Comment: write console.log(days) and see if you are getting anything in the console window.

Comment: I guess the text box has another id since you're using ASP.NET.

Comment: Set textbox ClientID mode to Static or try $("<%=numOfDays.ClientID%>").val(days),before that log or alert days value to make sure days has valid value.

Comment: The textbox has same id as the one on your code Kristoffer.

I have also tried both console.log(days) and `$("<%=numOfDays.ClientID%>").val(days)`

I am wondering if I need something like onChange event or something?

Also, just to be sure I am using Kristoffer's code correctly, I am wondering if it is a separate js. I incorporated it into my original code.

Comment: You don't need a separate js file for that. So what did console.log output?

Comment: @Kristoffer, nothing, that's what I said in my last post.

I have updated  my code above to include yours.

Comment: Ok, this is working now. I played around with your code by moving it to the first datepicker initialization and that did the trick.

Thanks for your help.